# Issues with Powershell variables/expressions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a Get-Winevent command using variables, but I'm having issues with variables inside "built" commands and I've hit the proverbial brick wall. On the last bit of code, if I remove $EventIDQueryAdd and $EntryTypeQueryAdd the command runs without issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
$ArgLastMinutes = 60
$ArgLogName = "Security"
$ArgEntryType = 0 
$ArgEventID = 4625
if ($ArgEventID) { $EventIDQueryAdd="id=$ArgEventID;" }
if ($ArgEntryType) { $EntryTypeQueryAdd="level=$ArgEntryType;" }

write-host "argeventid "$ArgEventID # returns 4625
write-host "argentrytype "$ArgEntryType # returns 1
write-host "eventidqueryadd "$EventIDQueryAdd # returns id=4625; as it should
write-host "entrytypequeryadd "$EntryTypeQueryAdd # returns level=1; as it should
$LogEntries=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="$ArgLogName"; $EventIDQueryAdd $EntryTypeQueryAdd StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes) } 
... Loop through LogEntries ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What was the error message? :-)

In the last line of code, it looks like you're missing either the key names for `EventIDQueryAdd` and `$EntryTypeQueryAdd` or an `=` sign between the two (and some semi-colons).

```
$LogEntries=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="$ArgLogName"; $EventIDQueryAdd $EntryTypeQueryAdd StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes) }
```

Recall that a hash is a collection of key-value pairs. Just values don't make sense.

One options, using `$EventIDQueryAdd` (with the value 'EventIDQueryAdd') as a key with a value of `$EntryTypeQueryAdd` (with the value 'EntryTypeQueryAdd'):

```
PS C:\>@{logname="$ArgLogName"; $EventIDQueryAdd=$EntryTypeQueryAdd; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes)}

@{logname="$ArgLogName"; $EventIDQueryAdd=$EntryTypeQueryAdd; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes)}

Name                           Value                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                        
logname                        LogName                                                                                      
StartTime                      2015-04-02 12:56:25 AM                                                                       
EventIDQueryAdd                EntryTypeQueryAdd
```

Another option using different key names:

```
PS C:\> @{logname="$ArgLogName"; SomeKey1=$EventIDQueryAdd; SomeKey2=$EntryTypeQueryAdd; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$ArgLastMinutes)}

Name                           Value                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                        
SomeKey1                       EventIDQueryAdd                                                                              
logname                        LogName                                                                                      
StartTime                      2015-04-02 12:58:05 AM                                                                       
SomeKey2                       EntryTypeQueryAdd
```